# What does the slice operator img[:,:,::-1] with images do?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am a novice with image processing and came across a blog that demonstrates using the slice operator to flip an image, which I require for a Machine Learning task.

I tried implementing the same, by reading 3 channel images using OpenCV as below, and it doesn't work as expected!

All that the slice operator is doing, is converting a BGR image to an RGB one(No Flipping!).

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img = cv2.imread('path_to_image')
img = img[:,:,::-1]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

What am I missing over here???

Comment: Did you try to flip one of the first 2 ones?  like: `img = img[::-1,:,:]` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, it works. I'm curious about what went wrong with my code. Any explanation will help me understand the concept better. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You sliced the wrong part of the image array.

Images consist of `X`,`Y` and `BGR` values. By slicing the last index you only inverteded the `BGR` to `RGB`.

To mirror the image you need to reverse either the `X` or the `Y` cooords wich are the indexes on 0 and 1 of the image - index 2 is `RGB`:

```
img = img[:    ,:    ,::-1]  # reverses BGR to RGB, keeps x and y as is
```

Instead you do

```
img = img[:    ,::-1 ,:   ]  # reverses the x coords - mirror on x
img = img[::-1 ,:    ,:   ]  # reverses the y coords - mirror on y
```

etc.

### BGR:

[image: BGR]

### RGB:  `img1 = img[:, :, ::-1]`

[image: RGB]

### FLIP Y:  `img1 = img[::-1, :, ::-1]`

[image: FLIP Y]

### FLIP X:  `img1 = img[:, ::-1, ::-1]`

[image: FLIP X]

### FLIP X,Y:  `img1 = img[::-1, ::-1, ::-1]`

[image: FLIP X+Y]

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Artner for the exposition, makes things clear! Also, I was unaware until now that OpenCV reads images as [width, height, channels].

Comment: @Nizam It should be [height, width, channels].